# Selenium Grid is not running multiple test in parallel for same browser without testNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have a lot Java selenium e2e test to run, it is taking a long time, so I tried to use selenium grid to see if it can help.

1. I set up selenium Grid hub: 
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -host 127.0.0.1
2. I started three nodes:
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444 -host 127.0.0.1

Then in my code,

```
wd = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);
```

Then I run it in my intelliJ directly, when I monitor the nodes console, I only see one node is used, other two nodes are not used and tests are still running one by on in sequency.

Any other thing I need to do to make all the tests running in parallel?

I am not using testNG, most material on line is testNG solutions there and for multi browsers, such as firefox and chrome. I just want to run in chrome in paralle here.

Thanks

Comment: IntelliJ still has to use TestNG, JUnit or some sort of testing framework to execute tests. What test framework are you using if not TestNG?

Comment: just regular jUnit with Selenium directly